# How to make a shortcut to Local Area network (LAN) Settings

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, keyboard-shortcuts

My goal is to make a shortcut to the place: **Local Area Network(LAN) Settings**
I have so far made a **New shortcut** where I put in target:

`C:\Windows\System32\control.exe Inetcpl.cpl,Connections,4`
Start in: `C:\Windows\System32`
Shortcut key: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>

This makes the **Internet Properties** window appear
and also the tab **Connections**.

I want make the shortcut go further to the button same tab **LAN settings**.

Comment: Depending on why you're doing this `netsh` might be able to directly apply changes.

Comment: Netsh I never used that before I'll look into that hmm.

Comment: It really depends on what you're doing but if you're just looking at changing between two sets of IPs setting up a script to change to Set1 and one to change to Set2 might be nice thing instead of just opening that dialog.

Comment: actually what I want it's  to have a shortcut to Check/Uncheck the the box Use automatic configuration script

Comment: I'm not sure whenever or not `netsh` could help in that case. Proxy settings can be a pain as there are several mechanism in windows.

Comment: Yeah I seen people make scripts that changes the values in the regedit it feels so wrong to to that, to make something such simple indeed but it's of course windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you can't shortcut directly to there, however if you hit `ALT` + `L` while at the `C:\Windows\System32\control.exe Inetcpl.cpl,Connections,4` window that will take you to it.

Comment: No it will not though.

Comment: It does for me, tested in Windows 7 & 10

Answer (score 5):

1. Right Click on Desktop. Select New > Shortcut.
2. in Create Shortcut dialog box it will ask you for Type the location of the item:
   put **rundll32.exe inetcpl.cpl,LaunchConnectionDialog** in the text box.
3. Do not click on browse button.
4. Click on Next Button to continue.
5. Type a name for the shortcut i.e. **Proxy Settings**.
6. Click on Finish.
   Your shortcut has been created

Answer (score 2):

<sup>(...assuming this was an "[XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/370758)")</sup>

If the OP's goal was actually to have easy access to **toggle the IE Proxy Server on or off**, then [this simple utility](http://www.dcmembers.com/skwire/download/ie-proxy-toggle/) from Jody Holmes could be the easiest solution.  (Works in Windows XP/Vista/7/8/10.)

It adds an icon to the notification area, with which a single click will toggle to [image: a] **Enable** or [image: b] **Disable** the proxy server "checkbox" in Internet Options, eg: <sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub>[image: checkbox]</sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub>

**Right-click** the icon for more options including icon update frequency, and ability to set a hotkey. From "About":

---

### **Command-line usage:**

```
ieproxytoggle -on
ieproxytoggle -off
ieproxytoggle -toggle
```